# Discord.js: roles.some(r => !message.member.roles.cache.has(r)) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I am switching from single STAFF command (e.g. `if(message.member.roles.cache.has(staff_id))`) to more flexable method - if member has either helper or mod or admin role, etc. I used `some` method with array like this:

```js
const roles = [
  "859471924753072188",
  "836214627243262002",
  "922170188089139261",
  "836214626923315221",
  "922170903394127873",
  "859878718599987200",
  "836214626617655296"
]
const isntStaff = roles.some(r => !message.member.roles.cache.has(r))
```

And now whenever I use this in some code, for example in this one:

```js
...
if (
    rudeWords.some(word =>
      message
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(word)
    ) &&
    isntStaff
  ) {
    message.delete({ reason: `Blacklisted Word Detected` });
    message.channel
      .send({ content: `${message.author}, do not use that word here, thank you.` })
      .then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000)
  })
```

it just doesn't let me to use the word even if I have helper or mod or admin command.
It also logs nothing in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also another way to do this according to this [Discord.js Guide](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md#check-if-a-member-has-a-role).

This is an example of how you could do this:

```
// Check if they have one of many roles
const roles = [
  "859471924753072188",
  "836214627243262002",
  "922170188089139261",
  "836214626923315221",
  "922170903394127873",
  "859878718599987200",
  "836214626617655296"
]

if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => roles.includes(r.id)) ) {
  // has one of the roles
}else {
  // has none of the roles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires every single one of those roles. You are checking if there are any roles in that array that *aren't* in the member's role cache. Instead, put the `!` on the outside

```js
const roles = [
  "859471924753072188",
  "836214627243262002",
  "922170188089139261",
  "836214626923315221",
  "922170903394127873",
  "859878718599987200",
  "836214626617655296"
]
const isntStaff = !roles.some(r => message.member.roles.cache.has(r))
```

Comment: `roles.every(r => !message.member.roles.cache.has(r))` works as well but I'd guess `Array.prototype.some` is more perfomant in this scenario.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it still doesn't let me. no errors, nothing...

Comment: @lusc both dont work for me.